# Error message in outputting API data: "[object Object] success [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I am trying to load JSON-encoded data from a currency API using a GET HTTP request. I made the get http request; however I get a [object Object] success [object Object] when I try to output.

Here is my code:

```js
var url = "https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/currencies";
var url2 = "https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=USD_PHP,PHP_USD"
$.when(
    $.getJSON(url, {
      format: "json"
    }),
    $.getJSON(url, {
      format: "json"
    })
  )
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    $.each(data, function(i, field) {
      $("#results").append(field + " ");
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#results").append(field + " ");`

`field` is an object, and when the `toString()` method is called, you get `[object Object]`

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may want to chose something like

`$("#results").append(JSON.stringify(field));`

or

`$("#results").append(JSON.stringify(field, null, 2));`

Answer (score 0):

The `.done()` function gives you an array of values for each request that was resolved, so since you made 2 requests it will have 2 arguments. Each one will be an array with 3 items, the first one contains the data from your request.
It is accessible via the results property.
Since you used getJSON as you request method your data is return as an object and if you try to turn an object onto a string via adding you're going to get `[Object object]`, instead use `JSON.stringify`

```js
var url = "https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/currencies";
var url2 = "https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=USD_PHP,PHP_USD"
$.when(
    $.getJSON(url, {
      format: "json"
    }),
    $.getJSON(url2, {
      format: "json"
    })
  )
  .done(function(data1, data2) {
    $("#results1").append(JSON.stringify(data1[0].results));
    $("#results2").append(JSON.stringify(data2[0].results));
  })
```

```css
div{
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    margin: 1em 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results1"></div>
<div id="results2"></div>
```

Comment: So I got the results displayed in string format. HoweverI I want to access all the currency id data from the returned data; I tried something like this: $("#results").append(JSON.stringify(data[0].results.id))